# SQL Server concatenation -- two string variables -- what am I missing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why doesn't this give expected result?

```
DECLARE @1 char(90);
DECLARE @2 char(90);
DECLARE @3 char(90);


Set @1 = 'first part';
set @2 = 'second part';

set @3 = @1 + @2;

print  @3;  -- outputs 'first part'  where did 2nd part go?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part is `char(90)` so it gets padded to fixed size 90 with spaces. `@3` is also 90 chars so it is full just with the contents of `@1`. Switch to `NVARCHAR(4000)`. Never use `char` except if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Why nvarchar and not varchar?

Comment: @Ben because it is unicode and removes lots of charset concerns. Use it when you can. Just works.

Comment: nvarchar is more 'future proof' than varchar, and you don't have as many issues around collations, character sets etc. It does take twice the space though.

Comment: @ElectricLlama good points. With Enterprise Edition and row compression it does *not* take more space for many real-world characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can trim `@1` and `@2` and see *more* of your result (perhaps all of it if it fits into the `CHAR(90)` of `@3`).

```sql
SET @3 = RTRIM(@1) + RTRIM(@2);
```

Also, as @usr mentioned, you can make `@3` larger to accommodate `@1`and `@2`. `CHAR(180)` would work as well as his suggestion of `NVARCHAR` (or `VARCHAR`).